# Docker compose fails with connection error although there is internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 470B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:5.6-fpm                                                         25.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/composer:latest                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [composer 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/composer                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/php:5.6-fpm@sha256:4f070f1b7b93cc5ab364839b79a5b26f38d5f89461f7bc0cd4b  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                       1.8s
 => => transferring context: 51.53MB                                                                                    1.7s
 => ERROR [stage-1 2/7] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y      git      curl      wget      unzip          121.8s
 => [composer 2/3] COPY / /app                                                                                          2.2s
 => [composer 3/3] RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts                                             1.1s
------                                                                                                                       
 > [stage-1 2/7] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y                                   git                         curl                                     wget                                    unzip:                                       
#0 76.47 Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                          
#0 76.48 Ign:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release                                            
#0 76.48 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages                                  
#0 76.48 Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
#0 76.48 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 76.48 Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
#0 76.49 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 76.49 Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
#0 76.49 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 76.49 Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
#0 76.49 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 76.49 Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
#0 76.49 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 76.49 Err:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
#0 76.49   Unable to connect to security.debian.org:http: [IP: 151.101.194.132 80]
#0 121.6 Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
#0 121.6   Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (199.232.46.132), connection timed out
#0 121.6 Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
#0 121.6   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 121.7 Reading package lists...
#0 121.7 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 121.7 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (199.232.46.132), connection timed out
#0 121.7 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
#0 121.7 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to security.debian.org:http: [IP: 151.101.194.132 80]
#0 121.7 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y \t\t\t\t\tgit \t\t\t\t\tcurl \t\t\t\t\twget \t\t\t\t\tunzip" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

I have fully functional internet connection but when I try to do `docker compose up`, this error happens saying it cannot connect to the IP adderss, but it's accessible through my browser.

What should I look for to fix this? My machine is Ubuntu 22.03, docker installed correctly, and the same compose file works in Manjaro.

Comment: It could be anything from a firewall issue to a Docker network issue or something yet unknown.  Does internet work inside any of your Docker containers?  Does the build work without `docker-compose`?  Does your Docker compose file define its own network for the associated containers?  Please add any information about the Docker network setup, or any information about the contents of the Dockerfile or the Docker compose file so there is more information to diagnose possible causes.

Comment: First try whether docker has proper internet access at all. Try `docker run -it busybox ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`